# If $(a_n)_n\subseteq \Bbb{R}$ and $\left\langle T,\varphi \right\rangle=\sum^{\infty}_{n=0}a_n\varphi(n)$, then $T\in D'(\Bbb{R}).$

Tags: functional-analysis, distribution-theory

> Let $(a_n)_n\subseteq \Bbb{R}$ such that $$\left\langle T,\varphi  \right\rangle=\sum^{\infty}_{n=0}a_n\varphi(n).$$
>   I want to prove that $T\in D'(\Bbb{R}).$

**My trial**

It suffices to prove that $T\in l^1_{loc}(\Bbb{R})$. That is,
$$ \sum^{\infty}_{n=0}\left|a_n\varphi(n)\right|<\infty.$$
 Let $\varphi\in D(\Bbb{R})$, then there exists $a>0$ such that $\text{supp}\varphi\subseteq [-a,a]$, where supp is the support of $\varphi$.

$$\left|\left\langle T,\varphi  \right\rangle\right|\leq \sum^{\infty}_{n=0}\left|a_n\right| \left|\varphi(n)\right|\leq \sup_{n\in [-a,a]} \left|\varphi(n)\right|\sum^{\infty}_{n=0}\left|a_n\right|.$$
Since $(a_n)_n\subseteq \Bbb{R}$, I am not sure that $\sum^{\infty}_{n=0}\left|a_n\right|<\infty.$ So, I am stuck here, as I don't know how to proceed. Any help, please?

Comment: The only $a_n$ that matter are the ones for $n\leq a$

Comment: @Max: The ones such that $n\leq a$? How?

Comment: $\displaystyle|\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n\varphi(n)| = |\sum_{n\leq a} a_n\varphi(n) + 0| \leq ||\varphi||_K \displaystyle\sum_{n\leq a } |a_n|$

Comment: @Max: You made a point.